# Navegação sem refresh não muda a url!

Tags: javascript

Bom, pesquisei sobre uma navegação sem refresh, deu certo, porém ela não muda a url da barra de pesquisa do navegador, como eu posso fazer para que ela mude? Aqui esta o meu codigo do js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var content = $('#content');

    //pre carregando o gif
    $('a').live('click', function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        content.html( '<div class="loader"></div>' );

        var href = $( this ).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            success: function( response ){
                //forçando o parser
                var data = $( '<div>'+response+'</div>' ).find('#content').html();

                //apenas atrasando a troca, para mostrarmos o loading
                window.setTimeout( function(){
                    content.fadeOut('slow', function(){
                        content.html( data ).fadeIn();
                    });
                }, 500 );
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Apenas a título de introdução ao assunto, esta tarefa não é tão primária quanto possa parecer. Mudar a URL programaticamente até é simples. Existem duas formas: um sistema de hash (colocar um #hash) depois da url, ou realmente mudar o caminho através do [api history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method). Mas existem várias preocupações extras que você precisa ter. Por exemplo, você tem que pensar em configurar o servidor (no caso de usar a history api) para renderizar as rotas fantasmas com mesmo conteúdo.

Comment: E, usando qualquer das duas opções, você terá que preparar seu código para, quando o usuário entrar, carregar o conteúdo correspondente. O tema que você procura é rotas javascript, e existem algumas biblioteca por aí como [esta aqui](https://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/) ou [esta](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo).

Comment: Por fim, outra coisa é manutenção dos states da página: o usuário clica, volta, clica de novo, avança, volta, e você terá que manualmente ter controle de todo o estado da sua aplicação (já que ela não reseta) em algum lugar. Mas isto depende da complexidade do seu sistema, claro. Uma última coisa, só para ilustrar, mudar as rotas no cliente normalmente é um conceito aplicado em SPA (single pages applications) e em bibliotecas como angular (ngRoute), React (react-routes) etc.

Comment: @mrlew como posso fazer algo que reseta? pode me ajudar? sou novo em js

Comment: Se você é novo em js, definitivamente não recomendo escrever um sistema de rotas do zero. Se sua aplicação não é SPA, grandes chances de você nem precisar. Ou utilize uma solução pronta (biblioteca). De qualquer forma, só fiz um breve comentário. A pergunta original sobre como mudar a url tem uma resposta simples. Só apontei algumas repercussões pra você analisar se precisa disto. Essa sua última pergunta é ampla demais e foge do escopo da pergunta original e do escopo deste site. Recomendo um estudo sobre a linguagem desde seus fundamentos. A evolução vem com o tempo. Abraços e boa sorte.